# Error Using $this when not in object context (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\assetgate\resources\views\vendor\livewire\bootstrap.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-livewire

in my project dashboard i wanted to show products summary categorywise and created a livewire component `CatwiseSummaryComponent` inside dashboardinfo directory like below:

```
    \<?php

    namespace App\\Http\\Livewire\\Dashboardinfo;

    use Livewire\\Component;
    use Livewire\\WithPagination;

    class CatwiseSummaryComponent extends Component
    {
        protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

        use WithPagination;

        $title = "Categorywise Summary";
            
        return view('livewire.counter',\[
        'catwiseproducts' =\> DB::table('products')
                          -\>join('product_categories', 'products.product_categories_id', '=', 'product_categories.id')-\>select(
                        
                        'product_categories.id',
                        'product_categories.catName as Products', 
                        DB::raw('count(products.product_categories_id) as Total'),
                        DB::raw('sum(products.unitprice) as Totalprice'))
                     -\>groupBy('products.product_categories_id')
                     -\>orderBy('Products','asc')
                     -\>paginate(7),'title'=\>$title
            \]);
        }
    }
```

And in my component blade catwise-summary-component.blade.php I just inserted the following code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table align-middle mb-0">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Category</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Total Number</th>        
        <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    
        @foreach($catwiseproducts as $prod)                                                      
        <tr>
        <td>
            {{$prod->Products}}
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="fw-bold text-pink">{{$prod->Total}}</td>
        
        <td class="fw-bold text-secondary">{{number_format($prod->Totalprice,2)}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table> 
<p>{{$catwiseproducts->links()}}</p>
</div>
```

And to view this i was just calling `<livewire:dashboardinfo.catwise-summary-component/>` But this is showing an error like this:

```
Using $this when not in object context (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetgate\\resources\\views\\vendor\\livewire\\bootstrap.blade.php)
```

I want a solution for this Laravel Livewire problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is syntax error in your Livewire component code, You've declared return statement inside the class itself without any method scope. You must code it inside render method like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Dashboardinfo;
use DB;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class CatwiseSummaryComponent extends Component
{
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        $title = "Categorywise Summary";

        return view('livewire.counter', [
            'catwiseproducts' => DB::table('products')
                ->join('product_categories','products.product_categories_id',
 '=', 'product_categories.id')
                ->select(
                    'product_categories.id',
                    'product_categories.catName as Products',
                    DB::raw('count(products.product_categories_id) as Total'),
                    DB::raw('sum(products.unitprice) as Totalprice')
                )
                ->groupBy('products.product_categories_id')
                ->orderBy('Products', 'asc')
                ->paginate(7),
            'title' => $title
        ]);
    }
}
```